# Can't get customer ParamConverterProvider working, DropWizard 0.7

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

In my run method I have:

```
environment.jersey().register(DateTimeParamConverterProvider.class);
```

But on application start-up I get:

```
ERROR [2015-09-04 15:02:15,405] com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors: The
following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or 
provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public org.joda.time.DateTime 
scot.mygov.pp.services.rest.DateDimensionExtResource.findByTimestamp(org.j
oda.time.DateTime) at parameter at index 0
```

Here my findByTimestamp method is just something I was playing around with, whilst trying to get this to work.

I listed the registered providers during debug, like this:

```
Set<Class<?>> providerClassesAfter =
   environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getProviderClasses();
```

And got this list of registered providers:

```
class io.dropwizard.jersey.caching.CacheControlledResourceMethodDispatchAdapter
class io.dropwizard.jersey.guava.OptionalResourceMethodDispatchAdapter
class io.dropwizard.jersey.guava.OptionalQueryParamInjectableProvider
class com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartConfigProvider
class com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide
class org.mygovscot.util.json.DateTimeParamConverterProvider
```

So my provider would seem to have registered ok. Can anyone tell me why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropWizard 0.7 uses Jersey 1.18, which implements javax.ws.rs 1.1, which does not support ParamConverterProvider. (Later versions of DropWizard are on Jersey 2+).